# Redirect link to distribution slack app

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack-api

I'm trying to redirect URL to distribute ([OAuth 2.0](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth))my slack app with API gateway and lambda function (AWS) but I can't realize how to get the code.
the event that returns is null.

My lambda code :

```
// Lambda handler
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

   var messageTest = { 
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            code: event.code
        };

        var queryTest = qs.stringify(messageTest);
        https.get(`https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?${queryTest}`, (res, err) => {
         console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
            console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

            var data = [];
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
            var result = JSON.parse(data.join(''))
            console.log(result);
            });
        });    

        callback(null);
};
```

My redirect URL is the lambda URL.
The event that i get is null.

How can i get the "code" from the oAuth 2.0?

Comment: That's not code for a Lambda handler. Where's the `callback`? What's `codeone`?

Comment: You are right. I edit and fix my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Lambda Proxy integration (and therefore you don't use a Body Mapping Template), the JSON payload that you send to your API Gateway will be received by your Lambda as a stringified JSON in `event.body`.

So, you'll need to parse that first and you can get your `code`.

```
const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
const code = body.code
```

Reference: [Input Format of a Lambda Function for Proxy Integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format)

Comment: I didn't enable the Lambda Proxy integration until you remind me of that, Thank you, it's work.